# ImportError: cannot import name 'app'

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have been working on this for 5+ hours and it seems like it should be rather simple. I followed the [instructions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file) to set up a flask application on apache via mod_wsgi and after finishing them I am getting an error that

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

from the line:

```
from web_tool import app as application
```

of my wsgi file that is called web_tool.wsgi and looks like:

```
import sys  
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/web_tool/src/")
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)

from web_tool import app as application
```

My python version and system path are correct at least so I believe.

And then my virtualhost file, which is stored in apache2/sites-available/default looks like:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/opt/python-3.4.1

<VirtualHost *:4000>

    ServerName my.servername.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess web_tool user=my_username group=my_group threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/web_tool/src/web_tool/web_tool.wsgi
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    <Directory /path/web_tool/src/web_tool/>
        WSGIProcessGroup cnt_tool
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you see any errors, should my wsgi file be called the same as my python file? I'm running python 3.4 and mod_wsgi 3.4.

Comment: Is your `app` script in `/path/web_tool/src/web_tool/app.py`, or somewhere else?

Comment: it is in /path/web_tool/src/web_tool/web_tool.py

Comment: Haha well thanks so much for the quick comment, I was importing incorrectly, beacuse I thought wsgi needed the actual app object in the web_tool class but it needed that class first. It is working now thank the lawd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After being prompted by abarnert I realized that it wasn't a problem in the larger structure of Flask and Apache but simply with the structure of my import. So my solution that got it working was to make sure first that I did

```
from web_tool import web_tool as application
```

Because my project structure looks like

```
/path/web_tool/src/web_tool/
    web_tool.py
    web_tool.wsgi
```

I think naming the folder the same as the main python script the same confused but then I got it straight. Now the above import still didn't work because I got a module error but what did work was:

```
from web_tool import web_tool
application = web_tool.app
```

I didn't see this structure anywhere else online or in any other SO answers but that is probably because of my particular project structure.